# In Configurable Product How to avoid unassigning old products>

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

As u know if you created configurable products with drop menu attributes and published,
after this if u tried to assign new attribute to this created products, it will re-generated simple products for this configurable product and unassigned the old simple products that created in the first time

also want to add new attribute to current configrable product, without unassinged old products?

[image]

Like This!, so how to change flow of Disassociated product,and sustain them